# QTCreator: Tracepoints: How to print the value of a variable

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator

My question is simple, but I couldn't find an answer online.
How can I print the value of a variable in a tracepoint message ?
I know it's possible, but I forgot the formatting rules. I tried different kinds of brackets/braces around the variable name because I think it was done in a similar way, but nothing seems to work anymore.

[image]